# Please check if these two methods for inheritance and initialization are good or bad

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am new to JavaScript.  I know that many inheritance and initialization methods have been written and use some advance features like `Object.create`:

[Simple JavaScript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)

[Why Prototypal Inheritance Matters](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/)

For practice, I wrote my own methods for inheritance and initialization.  I have no idea if my code is good or if it could be improved.  Could someone help me and give me some advice?

```
function Class() {};

Class.prototype.create = function () {
    var constr = this.constructor; 
    var instance = new constr();

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var props = arguments[i];
        for (var name in props){
            instance[name] = props[name];
        }
    }   

    return instance;
}

Class.prototype.extend = function () {
    var constr = this.constructor;
    var proto = this.constructor.prototype;

    function ProtoClas() {};

    var prototype = ProtoClas.prototype = (function (proto) {
        function F() {};
        F.prototype = proto;
        return new F();
    })(proto); 

    ProtoClas.prototype.constructor = ProtoClas;

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var props = arguments[i];
        for (var name in props){
            prototype[name] = props[name];
        }
    }   

    return new ProtoClas();
}

Class.extend = function () {
    var args  = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);  
    return this.prototype.extend.apply(new this(), args);
}

Class.create = function () {
    var args  = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);  
    return this.this.prototype.create.apply(this, args);
}
```

I then generate a new Class and an instance through this Class:

```
var Person = Class.extend({
    say: function () {
        console.log("Hello");
    },
    walk: function () {
        console.log("walk");
    }
});

var person = Person.create({
    name:'lee'
})

console.log(Person);
console.log(person);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of [Why Prototypal Inheritance Matters](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/). It's good that you're taking an interest in prototypal inheritance. So let's review your code. I'll start with your use case and then discuss the implementation.

## The Use Case

```
var Person = Class.extend({
    say: function () {
        console.log("Hello");
    },
    walk: function () {
        console.log("walk");
    }
});

var person = Person.create({
    name:'lee'
});

console.log(Person);
console.log(person);
```

This code looks good. It's very similar to what I wrote in my aforementioned article. I would like to point out one thing though: you don't need two separate methods `extend` and `create`. Object creation and extension may be [combined into a single function](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/#combining_object_creation_and_extension). Hence you could do:

```
var Person = Class.extend({
    say: function () {
        console.log("Hello");
    },
    walk: function () {
        console.log("walk");
    }
});

var person = Person.extend({
    name: "lee"
});

console.log(Person);
console.log(person);
```

## The Implementation

Since you only require one method for prototypal inheritance I'll primarily focus on your `extend` function. First, your `Class.extend` method is needlessly complicated. I would rewrite it as:

```
function Class() {}

var extend = Class.prototype.extend = function () {
    //...
};

Class.extend = function () {
    return extend.apply(new Class, arguments);
};
```

As you can see you don't need to call `Array.prototype.slice` on `arguments`. It may be directly passed to `apply`. In addition try keeping things in variables as much as possible. Avoid expressions like `this.prototype.extend`. Also be explicit: write `new Class` instead of `new this()`.

---

Your `Class.prototype.extend` function is not only confusing but also wrongly implemented. It doesn't extend the given object `this`. Instead it extends `ProtoClas.prototype` which is actually just [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). I would implement `Class` as follows:

```
function Factory() {}

var CLASS = {
    extend: function () {
        Factory.prototype = this;
        var instance = new Factory;
        var length = arguments.length;
        var index = 0;

        while (index < length) {
            var prototype = arguments[index++];

            for (var property in prototype)
                if (instance[property] !== prototype[property])
                    Object.defineProperty(instance, property,
                        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prototype, property));
        }

        return instance;
    }
};
```

You may now use `CLASS.extend` as follows:

```
var PERSON = CLASS.extend({
    say: function () {
        console.log("Hello");
    },
    walk: function () {
        console.log("walk");
    }
});

var person = PERSON.extend({
    name: "lee"
});

console.log(PERSON);
console.log(person);
```

Note that instead of doing `var instance = Object.create(this)` I used a function called `Factory` instead. The reason for doing this is performance: `Object.create` creates a new constructor every time. Here I'm simply reusing a single `Factory` constructor.

In addition for each argument supplied to `extend` I copy all the properties of the argument to the instance only if it doesn't already exist. This check speeds up the process because every object inherits from `Object.prototype` and copying is a very expensive operation.

Also instead of copying the properties using `instance[property] = prototype[property]` I'm using `Object.defineProperty` and `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`. The allows you to copy properties as is allowing you to use getters/setters, etc.

## The Alternative

On a concluding note I would like to mention that true prototypal inheritance is slow in JavaScript because JavaScript [favors the constructor pattern of prototypal inheritance](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/#constructors_vs_prototypes) instead. Hence if you wish to write fast code then I suggest you read the following article which describes prototype-class isomorphism: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17893663/783743

Comment: Thank you very much, as you say recently I am interested in javascript inheritance, again I do an improved job on John Resig's Simple JavaScript Inheritance, inspired by your `Object.create` method, could help check it good or bad? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30018/i-do-an-improvement-job-on-john-resigs-simple-javascript-inheritance-please-ch